# iPhone timeIntervalSinceDate

Tags: iphone, date, format

I'm trying to measure time between taps.  I've gathered code from a couple other posts, but still no luck.  I running into issues when I'm taking the difference between two time stamps and trying to make it readable in seconds.

```
    // Time elapsed
NSTimeInterval duration = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:touchesBegan];

NSDateFormatter *formatted = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatted setDateFormat: @"ss"];

NSString *stringFromDate = [ formatted stringFromDate:duration];
```

The error comes on the last line where the formatting is supposed to occur:
Error:  Incompatible type for argument 1 of 'stringFromDate'

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `stringFromDate:` method of `NSDateFormatter` takes an `NSDate` as its argument. You are passing it an `NSTimeInterval`. `NSTimeInterval` is a double, containing a duration in seconds. So, you can get rid of the `NSDateFormatter` and simply generate a string using the duration like a double:

```
NSString *stringFromInterval = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", duration];
```